# PyCharm does not stop in debugging mode at the breakpoints in a QThread

Tags: python, pycharm, qthread

PyCharm does not stop in debugging mode at the breakpoints of a piece of code launched by QThread on a new installed station with fedora core 37 and PyCharm 2022.3.2.

What I don't understand is that it works perfectly with these same codes on two other stations running fedora core 33 with one PyCharm 2023.2.1 and the other Pycharm 2021.3.2 ...

I spent the day looking for a reason and a solution in vain (consulting stackoverflow tickets, pycharm forum, google ...).

Any suggestion to fix this issue will be very welcome.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark.  I have seen issues where PyCharm's idea of the path to the source I am setting the breakpoint in is different than the path that it has for the file being executed because of symlinks.  I think you can set a breakpoint by function name rather than line number.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What's really strange is that while breakpoints work very well for methods in the same module before QThread is used. That's why I thought of a link with QThread .... I'm going crazy with this story.

Comment: That is troubling.  Do you have any possibility of changing to the 2023.2.1 or 2021.3.2 versions (which you say are working on the older box) on this new box?

Comment: Good Idea ! I'm going to try this on Friday (I don't have access to the station before then). I'll let you know the result of course!

Comment: I see a ticket in pycharm support that might be related to this problem https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203420404-Pycharm-debugger-not-stopping-on-QThread-breakpoints but it's an old ticket. I can't believe it hasn't been fixed in the new versions ....

Comment: Same thing with pycharm 2021.3.2 ... I will certainly have to abandon pycharm ...

Comment: I've just installed LiClipse and launched it without reading the documentation with the default configuration and it works perfectly ... The issue seems to be with pycharm!